# Suppress certain Acronyms in the list

Tags: acronyms

I like the package `acronyms` very much, and I used it in my whole master thesis. I often used it just to write the same word the same in the whole work. For example I used `xa` for “x-Achse” but I never use the `\acs`. Therefore I dont want this acronym in the list. 
How can I change the script to just show acronyms where `\acs` was used in the document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

If by »but I never use the `\acs`« you mean you haven't used the acronym at all then the answer is quite simple: use `acronym`'s `printonlyused` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{foo}{bla bla bla}
  \acro{bar}{blubber blub}
\end{acronym}

\ac{foo}

\end{document}
```

If by »but I never use the `\acs`« you mean you *have used it* but only with `\acl` and never the short version then I'd try to do a search&replace and use the starred version of `\acl` in addition to `printonlyused`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{foo}{bla bla bla}
  \acro{bar}{blubber blub}
\end{acronym}

\ac{foo} \acl*{bar}

\end{document}
```